# VMnet1 host only network adapter

Tags: server, file-sharing

I need to copy the files from Windows to Ubuntu server and the server has only ssh client, no ssh server package installed. How can I do it?

Comment: Install an ssh-server?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is a bit old-tech, but you could try sneaker-net, with a USB drive.

Answer (score 0):

You could install an ssh server on your windows and pull everything to Linux via scp (or sftp).
You can install an ftp server on windows and pull everything via ftp client.
You can set up an NFS or SMB share on Windows, and pull everything over on Linux.

There are plenty different options. You don't have to push it from Windows to Linux, you can also pull it with Linux from Windows.

You can write the data on USB, mount the USB in your VM and copy the files too. Same with a CD/DVD.